# Date format :from varchar to integer

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i am having the date in the format like 'jan 2011' but if i use between 'jan 2011' and 'mar 2011' it is giving the wrong months
so i want to convert the varchar into the number format so that i can use between query in mysql 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should convert the varchar column to date column, which is more foolproof
(varchar lead to error prone)

use `find_in_set` to do the mapping

```
select find_in_set('jan', 'jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec');
```

so

```
select 
find_in_set(
  substring_index(col, ' ', 1),
  'jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec'
)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a real date column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table 
 ADD COLUMN the_real_date_column DATE;
```

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to insert a date value into that column:

```
UPDATE the_table  
   SET the_real_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(the_bad_date_column, '%b %Y');
```

---

`STR_TO_DATE` will insert a `0` for each value not supplied—in this case the day portion of the date. So you can increment the day to `1` like this:

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET the_real_date_column = the_real_date_column + 1;
```

Then you can query the date column normally, use `BETWEEN`, all that good stuff.
If seeing the old column bothers you, you can drop it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table 
DROP COLUMN the_bad_date_column;
```